# Crop screenshot in android programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap

for taking screen shot i have am using below code

```
  public void takeScreenShot(){
    File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/Hello Kitty/");
    if(!wallpaperDirectory.isDirectory()) {
    // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
    wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
    // create a File object for the output file
    }
    File outputFile = new File(wallpaperDirectory, "Hello_Kitty.png");
    // now attach the OutputStream to the file object, instead of a String representation
    // create bitmap screen capture
    Bitmap bitmap;
    View v1 = mDragLayer.getRootView();
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache(),0,0,v1.getWidth(),v1.getHeight());
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    OutputStream fout = null;


    try {
        fout = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
      //  Bitmap bitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(src)
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
        fout.flush();
        fout.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and now i want a cropped bitmap in that i want to crop some portion from left and some portion from bottom so i have used code like this

```
      Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache(),v1.getWidth()/10,v1.getHeight()/10,v1.getWidth(),v1.getHeight());
```

but i got an error

```
   08-29 23:41:49.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3486): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x +    width must be <= bitmap.width()
   08-29 23:41:49.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:410)
    08-29 23:41:49.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:383)
```

can anybody tell me how to crop portion of an bitmap from left and bottom thanks...

Comment: thanks brother i will update it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you misunderstood the usage of that specific [`Bitmap.create(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) function. Rather than supplying the source's width and height as the last two parameters, you should specificy the width and height the cropped result should end up with.

The error explains that since you specified an offset from the left and top, but passed in the source's dimensions, the cropped result would exceed the bounds of the original image.

If all you want to do is crop a tenth off the left and top, simply subtract the offsets from the original width/height:

```
Bitmap source = v1.getDrawingCache();
int x = v1.getWidth()/10;
int y = v1.getHeight()/10
int width = source.getWidth() - x;
int height = source.getHeight() - y;
Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, width, height);
```

Comment: but my friend Vote up require 15 reputation and i have not and i have accepted this answer as a helpful

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache(),v1.getWidth()/10,v1.getHeight()/10,v1.getWidth(),v1.getHeight());
```

You can use  `bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);`

Refer here for some more methods [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html)